# Correct sentence and paragraph casing

Tags: mysql

I have a database full of descriptions in all lower case.  This doesn't look very nice.  I am trying to figure out a way to correct the casing, ie., capitalize the first letter after every period, and after every Paragraph or new line.  Something along the lines of,

```
UPDATE table_name SET description = REPLACE(description, '.  a','.  A')
```

but of course looping through all possible cases, etc.

EDIT:  Here is an example.

***I need to change***,

this sentence needs to be properly capitalized.  and this sentence too.  there could be multiple sentences in this paragraph.

a new paragraph should be capitalized as well.  so it looks nicer.

***to this***,

This sentence needs to be properly capitalized.  And this sentence too.  There could be multiple sentences in this paragraph.

A new paragraph should be capitalized as well.  So it looks nicer.

Also, new lines are in the form of '\n'.  I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: This is _not_ a function that can be readily done with SQL.  Use some other programming language.